# perfect square checker says 144 is not a perfect square

Tags: python

I started learning python yesterday , and I realized I can make a perfect square checker using functions and the isinstance function. However , my code says 144 is not a perfect square. What am I doing wrong?

My Code :

```py
def sqrt():

    x = int(input("Enter a number:"))
    a = x ** 0.5
    return a

b = sqrt()

if isinstance ( b , int) == True:

    print("It is a perfect square")
if isinstance( b , int) == False:

    print("It is not a perfect square")
```

Comment: Please post codes not as images but as texts so others can replicate the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep in mind that `number ** 0.5` will always result to a floating value. Example: 144 ** 0.5 == 12.0. Because of this, `isinstance(b , int)` will always be False.

This is an alternative solution among many other possible solutions:

```
def is_perfect_square(number):
    root = int(number ** 0.5)
    return root ** 2 == number

print(is_perfect_square(144))
```

Comment: Alternatively a simple mod function can be used to check the difference between the float sqrt against the int sqrt.

Comment: One could also simplify the returns to `return root ** 2 == number`

Comment: in the return True and return False parts of your code , are True and False strings? why didnt you use else before the return False part?

Comment: @siddhantuniyal ```True``` and ```False``` are reserved keywords for boolean values. An else statement can also be added before the ```return False``` statement (this is just a shortcut applicable to certain cases).

Comment: @JoboFernandez - this will fail for rational numbers between 1 and 0, like 0.04.

Answer (score -1):

The type of `b` in the original code is a `float`.

you can see this by adding `type(b)` to the end of the code which would return `<class 'float'>`.

so you could change the code to this:

```py
def sqrt():

    x = int(input("Enter a number:"))
    a = x ** 0.5
    return a

b = sqrt()

if b - int(b) == 0:
    print("It is a perfect square")

else:
    print("It is not a perfect square")
```

This method avoids checking for type, but instead checks if the `decimal part == 0` which is sufficient for a square.

Note: there are other methods.

Comment: why is 12.0 - 12 = 0.0 not a float then?

Comment: that is a great question which is why i put there are other methods, some will use the `math` library and other the `decimal` library. But that is a separate question...  the OP asked what they are doing wrong...  but asnswering, it doesnt matter because not looking for `type` with this method. just checking if the **decimal part == 0**.

Comment: Be careful! This could give incorrect answers because of [floating point imprecision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken).

Comment: @CrazyChucky agreed,  one of the biggest issues in coding since its creation.